# Grouping COUNTs according to a given field in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by

I'm trying to display the number of appointments made at each of several locations within a given timeframe.  I know that I can group all appointments made during a given timeframe by using `GROUP BY`, for instance:

```
SELECT AP.start_datetime, AP.Patient_Name, AP.Status, AP.Location

FROM Appointment AP 

WHERE AP.start_datetime >= '2013.09.02 00:00:00.000'
AND AP.start_datetime <= '2013.10.02 23:59:00.000'

GROUP BY AP.Location
```

This will return all rows within the date range, with all appointments made at the same location grouped together.

However, I would like the output to follow the form:

```
**Location** | **Appointments**
Location1    | 123
Location2    | 412
Location3    | 341
...
LocationN    | 231
```

I'm having trouble finding the correct combination of `COUNT`/`SUM` and `GROUP BY` to make this possible.  I think my problem may be that I don't fully understand how `GROUP BY` functions.  I believe [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361946/how-to-count-and-group-by-a-certain-field-so-that-the-count-is-in-one-row) was asking the same question, though he didn't receive an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the query you listed in the question shouldn't even parse; you should get an error that start_datetime / parent_name / status are not in the GROUP BY clause. If you are grouping by location, what is the point of including start_datetime in the output, for example? If you only want one row for a given location, which start_datetime should it display? For what purpose? Try starting with this, which gets your desired results, and if you need other columns in the result set, then define that better:

```
SELECT 
  Location, 
  Appointments = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Appointment
WHERE start_datetime >= '20130902'
  AND start_datetime <  '20131003'
GROUP BY Location
ORDER BY Location;
```

Comment: That's true, I forgot about completing the `GROUP BY` clause.  And I'm sorry I was unclear: I have no desire to include start_datetime, nor any of the other fields, in the final output.  That first query was just a trimmed-down version of the best solution I had been able to come up with.  The extra data just served as a way to differentiate between distinct appointments.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should also work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Location,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Instrument) as Appointments
FROM Appointment
WHERE start_datetime >= '20130902'
  AND start_datetime <  '20131003'
```

Using this method avoids the parse error Aaron Bertand mentioned as

```
SELECT DISTINCT start_datetime, 
       Patient_Name, 
       Status, 
       Location,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Instrument) as Appointments
FROM Appointment
WHERE start_datetime >= '20130902'
  AND start_datetime <  '20131003
```

will parse. Whether it gives the same result though depends on your data

Comment: I don't think that OVER() clause will work on all versions (e.g. 2005) and in any case this does a lot more work than the simpler GROUP BY (just check the execution plan).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Location, Count(Location) AS Appointments 
FROM Appointment 
WHERE   start_datetime >= '2013.09.02 00:00:00.000'
        AND start_datetime <= '2013.10.02 23:59:00.000'
Group by Location
ORDER BY Location
```